# Python - Import file inside folder - No module found

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.9

Here is my file structure:

```
DoSomething.py
Helpers
   |------TextHelper.py
   |------MyConstants.py
```

Helpers folder contains 2 files - TextHelper.py and MyConstants.py. The TextHelper file contains methods that are used by DoSomething. The methods in TextHelper use the constants in the MyConstants file. The DoSomething file does not use the constants directly. Here are the import statements:

DoSomething.py

```
from Helpers import TextHelper
```

TextHelper.py

```
import MyConstants
```

Here is the entire MyConstants.py file

```
some_constant_1 = ""
some_constant_2 = 20
```

When I run DoSomething file, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<path>\DoSomething .py", line 10, in <module>
    from Helpers import TextHelper
  File "C:\<path>\Helpers\TextHelper.py", line 5, in <module>
    import MyConstants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyConstants'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Everything works fine when I move the TextHelper.py and MyConstants.py files to the same level as DoSomething.py(same parent folder)

Comment: Please also check the `dir` where you are launching this from.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a blank file in the `Helpers` directory:

```
__init__.py
```

So if you're using bash, just do:

```
cd Helpers
touch __init__.py
```

And your import in `DoSomething.py` will then work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding a blank __init__.py file did not work.  I am using Python 3.9

Comment: Adding this file should work. There is something you missed to say in your question. That is the correct way to do.